# Profile:Edit Registration returning error 'Decryption of form settings failed.'

Tags: profile-edit, mightybigrobot

When attempting to Register on a site, the user is getting the following error on submission of the Registration form:

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors:
Decryption of form settings failed.
```

This error occurs on a Production server after a recent move and was working on a previous server. It IS working on a local dev instance, just not on production. Running EE 2.5.5, MSM 2.1.5, Profile:Edit 1.1.1 which has all the patches mentioned in the MBR forums (https://mightybigrobot.com/forums/viewthread/9721/). Would appreciate any assistance as you can image it's a royal pain in the butt.

Thanks
Brendan

Comment: Has to be an environmental issue. I'd check the server system logs for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so thanks to Chris from Mighty Big Robot for his support call this morning, we tracked this back to the Terms of Service text area field being called rules:

```
<textarea name="rules" style="width:98%; margin-bottom: 1.5em;" class="textarea" rows="9" cols="90" readonly="readonly">
```

He changed this to the_rules and it fixed the initial problem:

```
<textarea name="the_rules" style="width:98%; margin-bottom: 1.5em;" class="textarea" rows="9" cols="90" readonly="readonly">
```

Now, it should be noted that this may point to an underlying problem with the server setup specifically to do with something call 'mcrypt'. I will pass this off to our hosting provider to see what they manage to discover and report back.

But for now, it's at least working again.